# DEPRECATED: The 'defaultProject' workspace option has been deprecated. The project to use will be determined from the current working directory

Tags: node.js, angular

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/material": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.10",
    "@ant-design/icons-angular": "^8.0.2",
    "@juggle/resize-observer": "^3.0.2",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^1.0.0-beta.4",
    "@ks89/angular-modal-gallery": "^7.2.5",
    "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^5.0.1",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^7.0.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^7.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^7.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^7.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "@nrwl/angular": "^15.9.2",
    "@schematics/angular": "^15.2.6",
    "@sentry/browser": "^4.3.0",
    "@types/c3": "^0.7.4",
    "@types/faker": "^4.1.5",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.36.0",
    "@types/highcharts": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/mapbox-gl": "^0.54.4",
    "@types/mousetrap": "^1.6.1",
    "airmap-contextual-airspace-plugin": "^1.2.0",
    "angular-crumbs": "^3.0.1",
    "angular-highcharts": "^8.0.2",
    "angular2-counto": "^1.2.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "c3": "0.7.11",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "core-js": "^3.30.1",
    "country-list": "^2.1.0",
    "d3-selection": "^1.4.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "factory.ts": "^0.5.0",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "hellosign-embedded": "^2.6.0",
    "highcharts": "^10.3.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.14.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "mousetrap": "^1.6.3",
    "ng-click-outside": "^5.3.0",
    "ng-contenteditable": "^2.1.1",
    "ng-intercom": "8.0.0",
    "ng-zorro-antd": "^7.5.1",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.3.9",
    "ngx-gallery": "^5.6.2",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^1.3.9",
    "ngx-mapbox-gl": "^9.1.0",
    "ngx-markdown": "^15.1.2",
    "ngx-scrollbar": "7.1.0",
    "ngx-stripe": "^7.4.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "sass": "^1.61.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.6.1",
    "time-ago-pipe": "^1.3.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  }
```

I am facing an issue while changing my project's node engine from 10x to 14x. Initially, I ran yarn install after npm install and then I got a deprecated error in my project.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me solve this error. I have attached the code of the error for reference.

> esbuild@0.17.8 postinstall D:\A\DroneEntry-pilot-enterprise\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\esbuild
> node install.js

> nx@15.9.2 postinstall D:\A\DroneEntry-pilot-enterprise\node_modules\nx
> node ./bin/compute-project-graph

> core-js@3.30.1 postinstall D:\A\DroneEntry-pilot-enterprise\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/android-arm@0.17.8 (node_modules@esbuild\android-arm):
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/android-arm@0.17.8: wanted {"os":"android","arch":"arm"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/android-arm64@0.17.8 (node_modules@esbuild\android-arm64):
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/android-arm64@0.17.8: wanted {"os":"android","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Answer (score 1):

delete from angular.json

```
"defaultProject": <your_project>
```

Answer (score -1):

in **angular.json**, search on this word *schematics*. and try to change this code

```
"schematics": {
"@schematics/angular:component": {
  "styleext": "scss"
}
```

},

to this code

```
"schematics": {
"@schematics/angular:component": {
  "style": "scss"
}
```

},